# PHPExcel - change font face for all document

Tags: php, pdf, fonts, phpexcel

I want convert excel to pdf. In process of converting I need to change font face. I found setting font face for single cell. Is it possible to set font face for all document?

```
$phpExcel = new PHPExcel();

$styleArray = array(
    'font'  => array(
        'bold'  => true,
        'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000'),
        'size'  => 15,
        'name'  => 'Verdana'
    ));

$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->setValue('Some text');
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

Answer (score 9):

**Option #1**

Set a default style for the entire workbook (all worksheets)

```
$phpExcel->getDefaultStyle()
    ->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

**Option #2**

Apply the style to a range of cells (the entire worksheet in this case) on each individual worksheet

```
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle( $phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->calculateWorksheetDimension() )
    ->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```